# How to share image with text to Facebook timeline using ShareKit?

Tags: ios, facebook, ios6, sharekit, facebook-timeline

I'm using ShareKit for sharing items to social networks. And I've faced with this issue. When posting to facebook in **iOS5**, using such code:

```
SHKItem * post;
post = [SHKItem image:imageView.image title:labelText];
[SHKFacebook shareItem:post];
```

I get a new message with photo and its description in my facebook timeline and also in photo album. But in **iOS6** I get only new photo with its description in the photo album. But I need that the new message was posted to my timeline too. What should I do?